# css - small image but the there's an "imaginary box" seen in firebug that stops me using a link?

Tags: css

I'm fairly new to css, sorry!

I have a site that is not up yet but it has a menu bar at the top of the page and below that a box with some text in, on the top left corner of that box there's a rosette. When I view the site with firebug on lower res screens the rosette which is only 50x100px covers a much larged area stopping me from clicking on the menu link.[image: The imaginary box viewed with firebug]

The box with the text in has it's own div,textbox

```
#textbox
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 45px;
width: 470px;
text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 35px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
background-image:url("../images/50.png");
}
```

The rosette also has it's own div, rosettepb

```
   #rosettePB {
    background-image:url("../images/rosette.png");
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 180px;
    margin: -140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 254px;
    width: 390px;
    z-index: 151;
    }
```

How do I get that box to be only 50x100px and thus not block that menu link?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the width and height for the box to be 390x180, so that's what it is. If you change it to 50x100, it will be smaller:

```
#rosettePB {
    background-image:url("../images/rosette.png");
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -140px;
    /*  position: absolute; */
    left: 30px;
    top: 344px;
    z-index: 151;
}
```

#### Edit:

As the background image is centered, you have to move the element to make the image appear at the same position. I adjusted the `top` positon, added a `left` positon and commented out the `margin`, as what I think would place the element correctly.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I think AlienWebguys solution would have worked too but I also had an issue with a mouse over effect that this fixed too. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @Andrew: Whether `z-index` would help depends on where the elements is in the document hierarchy. (Also, there is a known bug in IE regarding z-index which can complicate things.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your z-indexes. `z-index:151;` is a really high z-index and is probably sitting above your nav. Either lower that number or give your nav a higher z-index than the rosette:

```
#nav {
    position:relative;
    z-index:152;
}
```